# Parsing a diff file using grep/awk

Tags: diff, awk

I'm trying to parse a standard diff of some sql files to return only the delete sections.  I have been using grep with the after context (-A) which almost works (only because I know that delete sections will all be very short). e.g.

```
diff $$_$1.sql $$_$2.sql|egrep -A3 "[01234567889][01234567889]d[01234567889][0123456789]"
```

I am thinking that with AWK, I could tell it start at (the above regex) and stop at the first line starting with a digit or the first line ending with a --

I have played around a bit, but can't seem to find the right syntax to do this.  Can this be done with AWK? or is there another tool I should use?

Comment: Preferably an example of the `diff` output (or at least tell us what KIND of diff it is -- edit script, context diff, unified diff, etc.)

Comment: In addition to @voretaq7's questions, it'd also be worth knowing if you need the result to be a valid patch file afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am thinking that with AWK, I could tell it start at (the above
>   regex) and stop at the first line starting with a digit or the first
>   line ending with a --

Please give us an example if it is not what you want:

```
sed -n '/[0-9][0-9]d[0-9][0-9]/,/^[0-9]\|--$/p'
```

---

**EDIT**

Although you've accepted my answer but I still want to edit my post to share with you a regex that can help you solve your problem thoroughly. `sed` allows you [excluding the matching lines](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.24) with `b` - branch command:

```
sed -n '/[0-9][0-9]d[0-9][0-9]/,/^[0-9]\|--$/ { /^[0-9]/b; p }'
```

but with this regex, `sed` also remove the REGEX1. So, [Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) appears in my mind:

```
sed -n '/[0-9][0-9]d[0-9][0-9]/,/^[0-9]\|--$/ { /^[0-9](?:(?![0-9]d[0-9][0-9]).*)$/b; p }'
```

but it not works because the `sed`, `awk`, `grep` uses the POSIX RE flavor which [doesn't support](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) negative lookahead. You should try with Python, Perl, Ruby, ...

Comment: This is virtually perfect; I just missed a requirement.  I need it to be exclusive of the ending line but inclusive of the starting line.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to try to do this with unified diff and a simple grep:

```
diff -u a.sql b.sql | grep -v '^\+' | rediff
```

The `rediff` is going to try and fix up the offsets after you've mangled the diffs... it won't work in all circumstances, but it's the best hope you've got of keeping a valid diff.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff ... | awk '/start-mark/ {flag = 1} /end-mark/ {flag = 0} flag'
```

Your regex could probably be simplified to be `[0-9]` (etc.)

The `flag = 0` could be changed to `exit` if you only want to print the first matching range of lines.